# C# Winforms How to draw a rectangle on a button on a mouse over?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, paint

In our application we have white buttons on a white form. When the mouse hovers the button we want to show a light-blue transparant rectangle over the button.

I want to create this user control, but I don't know how to do this. I've tried google, but I didn;t found anything that could help me, so I hope you guys can point me at the right direction.

Comment: Do you want to change background color or for example draw rectangle around text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just derive your own WinForms control from a `Button` and override the `OnPaint` event. In the event handler you'll have an `PaintEventArg` parameter that contains the property called `Graphics`. You can use this property to draw anything you want directly where you control is located.

Here is an example directly from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx

Added: just re-read your question and found that I didn't not reply it correctly.

Basically, you have to override two events and add one property showing whether your control should be painted with an overlayed rectangle or not, let's say `IsDrawRectangle`. As soon as the `OnMouseEnter` event is triggered you check if IsDrawRectangle is set and if not you set it to true and invoke `this.Invalidate()`. The `Invalidate()` method will force the control to be re-drawn and then in your `OnPaint` event you just again check the value of your `IsDrawRectangle` property and draw the rectangle if needed. 
You also have to override `OnMouseLeave` to set the property back to false and force the repaint to remove the rectangle.

**Added:** if you need to re-draw more than just a single control (in case if your rectangle covers some other controls that need to be re-drawn) then put everything you want to be re-drawn in one container and call the `Parent.Invalidate()` method in your event handlers.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know when the mouse hovers the button, so I can draw the rectangle?